# Shorthand if statement - Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I have this function below which tells me if a user is in a specific group based on user and group arrays. Right now it's generating a table that says true or false. I'd like it to just mark an "X" if true and " - " if false.

This is the function:

```
function processAll(){
    for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++){
        userGroupTable[users[i]] = {};
        var userGroups = parseGroupCollFromUser(users[i]);
        for(var j=0; j<groups.length; j++){
            //if the array userGroups contains the current group, the value must be true
            userGroupTable[users[i]][groups[j]] = userGroups.indexOf(groups[j]) > -1; *think this line is whats giving the result
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the line to:

```
userGroupTable[users[i]][groups[j]] = (userGroups.indexOf(groups[j]) > -1) ? " X " | " - ";
```

but I get `Unexpected token ;`

Comment: Should be a colon ":" and not a "|"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about OP has a small typo error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use `:` instead of `|`.

It's `ternary operator` and it looks like this

```
$a === $b ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the `|` to a `:`, as in

```
userGroupTable[users[i]][groups[j]] = (userGroups.indexOf(groups[j]) > -1) ? " X " : " - ";
```